# getting data from another sheet using row and column number

Tags: microsoft-excel

how do i get the data from a cell in another sheet using the row and column number.

so say I want to get the cell contents from row 3, column 31 in my current worksheet, I can use

=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,31))

what about when im referencing a cell in another worksheet?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This question is lacking details needed for anyone to be able to help you. Please add details of what you have tried so far and exactly what you expect to accomplish. Giving an example of your data is always helpful. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

`=INDIRECT("'SheetName'!" & ADDRESS(3,31))`

OR just:

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,31,,,"SheetName"))`

for more information see [help on `ADDRESS()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ADDRESS-function-d0c26c0d-3991-446b-8de4-ab46431d4f89?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)